# How can i prevent explorer.exe from loading at startup?

Tags: process, batch-file, startup

How can i disable explorer.exe from startup?
(need it to boost my **only-gaming** pc)

Thanks!

**EDIT :**

I need to diable explorer.exe, the game starts automatically on startup!

If i want explorer back, i can simpely press: Cntrl + Alt + Del, start Task Manager, Click on New Task, and type: *"explorer.exe"*, it should work like that.

**EDIT 2:**

To make it On Topic, **Maybe i can do this with an Batch-file?**

I dont know enough of .bat files for making one, what i need to write in the batch-file?

Comment: kill the process after startup

Comment: How do you plan to start the game in the first place then? Weird idea.

Comment: I'm useing only 1 software (the game.. ) this wil startup automaticly on startup. I dont need such things as explorer.exe... Kill process after startup is not an option for me.

Comment: I don't think this belongs on Stack Overflow. Does it?

Comment: @AnishGupta I wrote the FAQ, and edited my post (edit 2).

Comment: Edit this reg key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and remove `explorer` from the `Shell` key, that will stop it loading, or put your own file in to start that instead of explorer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Windows, explorer.exe is the main file manager application that is required for the windows gui to function. Theoretically, there is a way to navigate your files (e.g., in order to open up your games) through the command line, though I believe that you will need explorer as the parent process for many of the popular games. Someone who has access to the MSDN would be able to tell you more definitively.

Long story short, unless you are booting into command line mode, explorer.exe will load on startup.

Comment: No.  Explorer does not have to start up with windows. You can even replaced it with another shell such as [Rainmeter](http://example.com).

Comment: You misunderstand. Explorer is the default file manager application. You can close it down, and navigate via command line or some other file manager (e.g., rainmeter). The problem is that most games use the windows defaults for things like saving games, loading games, etc. (When ever you see the default "save file" window, that is tied into explorer.exe). Unless the developer built their own file manager/navigator into the game, they will need to start up explorer.

Comment: <strike>(When ever you see the default "save file" window, that is tied into explorer.exe unless the developer built their own file manager/navigator into the game)</strike>

I may be mistaken about this part. I do not remember if the SaveFileDialog class needs explorer to be running as parent or not.

Comment: My mistake, rainmaker is not an explorer shell replacement. I thought it was more like [EmergeDesktop](http://emergedesktop.org/) which completely replaces the windows explorer shell.  The file dialogs are features of the windows API, they have a lot in common with windows explorer, but it is not a dependency.